# Change CSS element in the same linked sheet to 2 html files

Tags: html, css

My website pages are linked to a single CSS sheet, and I don't want to create another one just for one single detail.

I have a 'wrapper' id whose 'width' is 900px.
And a 'content' id whose 'width' is 540px, because there is a 'sidebar' on the right.

But in one of my pages, the photos one, I want the sidebar to disappear, and the 'content' div to take up all available space of the 'wrapper', it is to say 900px.

Is it possible to do it in the same CSS sheet? I wasn't able to find a solution but to create another file, that I have to keep changing because I modify the main one many times.

Comment: Add another class to your css file for what you want...

Comment: You can use class and toggle in each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alway override a style. There are three ways of achieving this that I can think of:

- Add inline styles to the element itself (in this case `style="width: 900px"`, the nearest declaration always wins)
- create and append a new  element, and add the text to override this style to it
- Modify the css rule itself by adding another declaration (#contetn2 or similar)

Override something already declared with the suffix `!important` like this:

```
content {
   width: 450px;
}

widecontent {
   width: 900px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example add attribute class to body element and use css selector weight to make changes only to desired page.